# Pandas incorrectly infers cx_oracle cursor datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I have to fetch data from an oracle database.

`pandas.read_sql` proved too slow so I moved to using the cx_oracle cursor.

The following piece of code correctly retrieves the data and the column names, unfortunately the inferred data type is wrong (for numbers).

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_oracle as cx
import sqlalchemy as sa

conn = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.prefetchrows = 1000
cursor.arraysize = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.execute(sqlQuery).fetchall(),
columns = [row[0] for row in cursor.description])
```

I know the data type is stored in `cursor.description` but I am not totally sure how to correctly retrieve it from there.

The following is not directly usable to declare the columns datatype in pandas:

```
dtype = [row[1] for row in cursor.description]
```

as the output looks like this:

```
[<cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_VARCHAR>,
 <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_NUMBER>,
 <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_VARCHAR>,
 <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_NUMBER>, # Pandas infers this as object
 <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_NUMBER>, # Pandas infers this as object
 <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_DATE>]
```

So, how do I correctly retrieve the datatype of my column?

It should appear clear that my final objective is to simply fetch from an Oracle database and parse into a pandas dataframe including column names and correct data types.
Feel free to suggest a better approach.

Comment: Can you chunk up the query and use pd.read_sql() with multiprocessing to speed this up, instead of using raw cursor?

Comment: I honestly didn't go that way as I don't think I would get that big of a performance improvement. Feel free to elaborate in an answer

Comment: Probably depends on your setup and database server capabilities, but in my experience running the queries in parallel caused a significant computation time reduce. Sorry, I'm not competent enough to justify why that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
## fetch db dtypes
dtype_db = [row[1] for row in cursor.description]

for idx, default_type in enumerate(dtype_db):
    if  (default_type == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_NUMBER) & 
               (df[df.columns[idx]].dtype=='object'):
        df[df.columns[idx]] = df[df.columns[idx]].astype(float)
```